# Sharepoint 2013 - How to rename the domain name?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2012-r2

On Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard we have Sharepoint 2013, AD, SQL Server 2014.

How do you change/re-config the domain name and IP addresses so that Sharepoint 2013 will run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the Active Directory domain, you use `rendom.exe` but it's highly recommended you do not do this once SQL Server is in place on the domain. Also, having Exchange in the mix will make it worse. It's a highly destructive operation and honestly, I'd stand up a new domain and move the servers into it. Fewer goblins left behind.

If you're talking about a web domain name and IP address, you need to provide more info on what "run correctly" constitutes.

A checklist for `rendom` is avilable [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816631(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: I just found this... UGH!
http://tharindupg.blogspot.com/2015/01/change-active-directory-of-sharepoint.html

and 

https://blog.varonis.com/risks-renaming-your-domain-in-active-directory/

Thanks for your input. It is now up to management as to what headache they want to choose.

Comment: I was asked to look into the feasibility of doing a `rendom` here and suggested we instead build a new domain in a new forest, set up a trust, and migrate the objects over that way. We need to do it for regulatory purposes. But there are very few situations where it should really matter _what_ the domain is. If it's for web access, you can adjust the bindings in IIS in a matter of minutes, same with setting up alternative certificates.